# How to construct a partial ordering from Peano's 5 Axioms?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, peano-axioms

I am trying to formally construct the usual partial ordering LTE from Peano's 5 Axioms. Would the following construction work?

$$\forall a,b: [(a,b)\in LTE \iff(a,b)\in N^2$$

$$\land ~ \forall c\subset N^2:[\forall d\in N: [(d,d) \in c]$$

$$ \land ~ \forall d,e:[(d,e)\in c \implies(d, S(e))\in c]$$

$$\implies (a,b) \in c]]$$

where $N$ is the set of natural numbers and $S$ is the usual successor function on $N$.

---

**EDIT:**

Informally, for all $x,y\in N$, we can recursively define $\le$ on $N$ as the *"smallest" set of ordered pairs of natural numbers that satisfies*:

$$x \le x$$

$$x\le y \implies x\le S(y)$$

Comment: In the second line, you switch from defining $LTE$ to making a statement about all relations, which seems like it's not what you want.

Comment: LTE means.... what?

Comment: @LeeMosher LTE (less than or equal) is a set of ordered pairs of natural numbers.

Comment: I think your definition is fine: You are saying that $a \le b$ holds if whenever $R$ (which you call $c$) is a relation on $N$ that is  reflexive and is such that $d\mathrel{R}S(e)$ whenever $d\mathrel{R}e$, then $a\mathrel{R}b$.That says that $(\le)$ is the intersection of all reflexive relations $R$ such that $(S \circ R) \subseteq R$, which is true.

Comment: Might be good to put that definition in your post; I am guessing that many more people know "less than or equal" than know "LTE".

Comment: ... but concerning your edit: there are many relations satisfying your "recursive" conditions: you need to choose the smallest such relation, which your more detailed definition does.

Comment: @RobArthan The formal definition is more precise. It gives the "smallest" subset of $N^2$ that satisfies the given conditions.

Comment: Exactly: your second edit makes that clear. Your proposed definitions (the formal one and the less formal one) are absolutely fine.

Comment: Added to edit...

Comment: And then following on from this definition, you can start thinking about exercises of how to prove things such as: $\forall a,b: a \le b \leftrightarrow S(a) \le S(b)$, and $\forall a: \lnot(S(a) \le a)$.

Comment: Do note that the definition involves some second-order logic, though.  Unless you're considering $N$ as being a set within some first-order set theory such as ZFC, or something along those lines.

Answer (score -1):

(Answering my own question)

Thanks all for your help, but I didn't find my construction here to be very workable. I was trying to avoid using an addition function to "simplify things." That was probably a mistake.

Using Peano's Axioms, some basic set theory and a form of natural deduction, I formally constructed (in order) the function $+$ and the relations $\leq$ and $\lt$ as sets of ordered n-tuples such that, for all $x, y \in N$ we have:

$x+0 = x$

$x+S(y) = S(x+y)$

$x\leq y \iff \exists z\in N: x+z=y$

$x \lt y \iff x\leq y ~\land ~ x\neq y$

Everything then fell into place. I was just now able to derive the usual fundamental properties of $+$, $\leq$ and $\lt$ for a larger project that I am working on.